# CSS not being applied to content within modal dialog in IE

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I recently wrote some code where I have several jQuery UI modal dialogs. In each of these modal dialogs, I didn't want the default titlebar provided by jQuery  so I used this line of code in the `create` function in  the dialog code :

```
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("display","none");
```

Then I just filled the content of the modal dialogs in this manner:

#### HTML

```
<div id="helpdialog" class="helpbox">
    <header id="helptitle">Help</header>    
    <p id="helptext">
        The aim of the game is to escape the maze by forming a correct sentence that ends on one of the edges of the grid.<br><br>
        From each square you can only move to one of the highlighted squares. Choose the only word that can correctly follow the word in the square that you are in and click on it.Move one square at a time, forming a sentence, until you reach one of the edges of the grid or until it is impossible to extend your sentence further. Click on Submit.<br><br>
        To undo your selections click on the squares you want to deselect in the reverse order to that in which you selected them (they will be numbered).<br><br>
        If you click on Reveal, the sentence will be shown for two seconds, and then you'll be able to resume playing.<br><br>
        In the Single player game find all of the sentences in the shortest time possible. 
    </p>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#helptitle {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d9d3ed;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: Dejavu, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#helptext { 
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: .5em;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 0; 
}
```

Well, the problem is that none of the CSS attributes seem to be applied to the `header` tag **only in lower versions of IE** . The  CSS for the `p` tag gets applied though. In all other browsers,it works fine. Do I need to use more specific selectors or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `<header>` tag is only supported [**as of IE9**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp), and not before.

One solution, would be to target all text in the div for the header, and then target more specifically for the paragraph text, e.g.

```
div {
    color:red;
}

div > p {
    color:blue;
}
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZHAz/) example.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel so stupid right now. Thanks for pointing that out. I need to use something like HTML5 Shiv then in my case I suppose?

Comment: @Ronophobia Check out my jsFiddle I just posted in my update :)

Comment: Yep that seems to be a better option :)

Answer (score 1):

This calls for the [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)!

Comment: I was thinking about that too.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IE 8 and below do not apply any styling to unknown elements.
Look [here](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html#unknown-elements) for more info.